# How to change a DataTable structure so columns values are in multiple columns?

Tags: c#, linq, collections, datatable, transpose

If i have a datatable with structure like that :

```
emp_num name  status  session_id

  22    john     0       4

  22    john     0       5

  34    moh      1       3

  35    Ran      0       3

  35    Ran      0       4
```

---

How to convert it to datatable like that :

```
emp_num name  status  session_id1  session_id2  session_id3  session_id4 session_id5 

  22    john     0       0             0               0            1          1

  34    moh      1       0             0               1            0          0   

  35    Ran      0       0             0               1            1          0
```

---

I try to create custom data table with looping but it's not generic ,I want something so generic so if i add more columns or the number of sessions increased i get no out of range exceptions ..

Comment: I think there is something fundamentally wrong with your approach. If there is a one-to-many relationship between your employees and sessions, you need to have two tables. one table for employees, where there is one row for each employee and another table for sessions, where there is one row for each session. Each session record should have a "emp_num" to link it back to an employee.

Comment: @Keith:yea there are two tables and i make a join between the two tables and set the result in datatable.now, i want a report with
the following structure `emp_num name  status  session_id1  session_id2  session_id3 ...` the number of columns depends on the session_id value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
using System.Data;
public static class DataTableExtensionMethods
{
    public static DataTable TransposeIntegerColumnIntoColumns(this DataTable dt, int indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, int integerColumnIdToTranspose, string transposedColumnName)
    {
        //Protection if the column to transpose is not an integer or doesn't exist
        if (integerColumnIdToTranspose >= dt.Columns.Count) return null;
        var columnDataType = dt.Columns[integerColumnIdToTranspose].DataType;
        if (columnDataType != typeof(int)) return null;

        //Get max sessions number
        int maxColumnNumber = 0;
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int? number = dr.Field<int?>(integerColumnIdToTranspose);
            if (number != null)
            {
                maxColumnNumber = Math.Max(maxColumnNumber, (int)number);
            }
        }

        //Protection if there are zero rows or the maxColumnNumber is 0
        if (dt.Rows.Count == 0 || maxColumnNumber == 0) return null;

        //Make a copy of the table so we can remove duplicate rows and add the transposed columns
        DataTable result = dt.Copy();

        //Add columns to store the session_ids
        for (int i = 1; i <= maxColumnNumber; i++)
        {
            DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(transposedColumnName + i.ToString(), typeof(int));
            dc.DefaultValue = 0;
            //Possibly make an overloaded method that supports inserting columns
            result.Columns.Add(dc);
        }

        //Remove rows with duplicated employees
        for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            int duplicateRow = GetRowIndexById(result, indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, result.Rows[i][indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows].ToString(), i + 1);
            if (duplicateRow > -1)
            {
                result.Rows.RemoveAt(duplicateRow);
            }
        }

        //Populate the transposed columns with values in the integer Column To Transpose
        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            int? sessionNumber = dr.Field<int?>(integerColumnIdToTranspose);
            if (sessionNumber == null) continue;
            int rowIndex = GetRowIndexById(result, indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, dr[indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows].ToString(), 0);

            result.Rows[rowIndex][transposedColumnName + sessionNumber.ToString()] = 1; //or +=1 if you want to increment the number
        }

        //Remove the integerColumnIdToTranspose (again overload this method if you want to keep this column)
        result.Columns.RemoveAt(integerColumnIdToTranspose);

        return result;
    }

   //Net 4 implementation with optional parameter
   //private static int GetRowIndexById(DataTable dt, int indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, string id, int startLookAtRow = 0)
    private static int GetRowIndexById(DataTable dt, int indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, string id, int startLookAtRow)
    {
        for (int i = startLookAtRow; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt.Rows[i][indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows].ToString() == id) return i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Calling code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DataTable dt = GetData();
    DataTable result = dt.TransposeIntegerColumnIntoColumns(0, 3, "session_id");
}

private DataTable GetData()
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Columns.Add("emp_num", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("name");
    dt.Columns.Add("status", typeof(int));
    dt.Columns.Add("session_id", typeof(int));

    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["emp_num"] = 22;
    dr["name"] = "John";
    dr["status"] = 0;
    dr["session_id"] = 4;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["emp_num"] = 22;
    dr["name"] = "John";
    dr["status"] = 0;
    dr["session_id"] = 5;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["emp_num"] = 34;
    dr["name"] = "Moh";
    dr["status"] = 1;
    //dr["session_id"] = null;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["emp_num"] = 35;
    dr["name"] = "Ran";
    dr["status"] = 0;
    dr["session_id"] = 3;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    dr = dt.NewRow();
    dr["emp_num"] = 35;
    dr["name"] = "Ran";
    dr["status"] = 0;
    dr["session_id"] = 4;
    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

    return dt;
}
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thank u so much for this effort.
but i use .net 3.5,so i encounter this error `Default parameter specifiers are not permitted` in the second method `private static int GetRowIndexById(DataTable dt, int indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, string id, int startLookAtRow = 0)`

Comment: Ok, copy/paste the code in the DataTable Extension Method class into your project, I made it .Net 3.5 compatible:)

Comment: i get the following exception :`Cannot cast DBNull.Value to type 'System.Int32'. Please use a nullable type` so i edit the following line to `int sessionNumber = dr.Field<int?>(integerColumnIdToTranspose) == null ? 0 : dr.Field<int>(integerColumnIdTo` but i get another exception `Column 'session_id0' does not belong to table .`

Comment: I did test this code. Weird. Adding that check for nullables is good, though I'm not sure how an exception is raised with this line: `int? sessionNumber = dr.Field<int?>(integerColumnIdToTranspose)` before the column **session_id0** is added.

Comment: I don't want `session_id0` i want the beginning `session_id1`

Comment: Thanks for that hint. See in my code see how I add the columns starting a 1: `for (int i = 1; i <= maxColumnNumber; i++) { DataColumn dc = new DataColumn(transposedColumnName + i.ToString(), typeof(int));`, maybe you changed this and thats why you get the exception. The code should start adding columns with **session_id1** not *session_id0*

Comment: No i didn't change the code , but sometimes i have data like this
`34    Moh      0       null` cuz the datatable result from `outer join`

Comment: Apologies for all the edits, I've tested this method with null sessions and it works. Let me know if you bump into any other issues? Cheers

Comment: Great, I'm grateful for U :]

Comment: :Could u edit your answer plz? i fix it as the following :
`for (int i = 0; i < result.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                int duplicateRow = GetRowIndexById(result, indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, result.Rows[i][indexColumnToEstablishDuplicateRows, DataRowVersion.Original].ToString(), i + 1);
                if (duplicateRow > -1)
                {
                    //result.Rows.RemoveAt(duplicateRow);
                    result.Rows[duplicateRow].Delete();
                }
            }
            result.AcceptChanges();`

Comment: `result.Rows.RemoveAt(duplicateRow);` remove the row completely so i have confusion in the loop so i replace it with `delete` the `acceptchanges` at the end :)

Comment: @JeremyThompson Excellent Solution Jeremy :)